# What is the Symfony2 equivalent of components in Symfony1?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony

In my Symfony2 application, I want to have a widget displayed on various pages. This can't just be defined by its template, it need to call the DB and go through the controller.

In Symfony1, I would create a component and include it. How can I do the same in Symfony2?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I did some more research, and the simplest way I found was just this simple line in the template:

```
{% render 'MyBundle:MyController:myAction' %}
```

This outputs the result of the action, with the template specified by the action.

Comment: more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#templating-embedding-controller

Comment: The signature of the render method has changed as of 2.2, it's now `{{ render(controller('MyBundle:Ctrl:myAction')) }}` Where `Ctrl` is the controller name without the ending `Controller` string. Check out http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/templating.html#templating-embedding-controller

Comment: more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html
(c33s' URL was changed)

Answer (score 8):

You can create Twig Extension with function `widget` and register it in the container. Also inject `Kernel` into this extension.

```
class WidgetFactoryExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $kernel;

    public function __construct($kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel= $kernel;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'widget' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'createWidget', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function createWidget($name, array $options = array())
    {
        list($bundle, $widget) = explode(':', $name);

        $widgetClass = $this->kernel->getBundle($bundle)->getNamespace() . '\\Widget\\' . $widget;
        $widgetObj = new $widgetClass();

        $widgetObj->setContainer($this->kernel->getContainer());

        if ($options) {
            $widgetObj->setOptions($options);
        }

        return $widgetObj;
    }
}
```

And after this write in templates:

```
{{ widget('QuestionsBundle:LastAnswers', {'answersCount' : 10}) }}
{# class QuestionsBundle/Widget/LastAnswers #}
```

Comment: OK, it's not wrong, but that's just reinventing `render`, and/or `include` ^^

Comment: What if we should put object/collection into widget?

Comment: Nope `render 'AcmeBundle:AcmeController:fooAction with {parameter: myObject}` :)

Comment: Have you seen last changes in core? As from 2.2 you should have routes for each actions which can be rendered in template. And parameters - just route parameters or query string. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/64d43c806bc1c00dda536305565d8aaa3d07b699#diff-0 . So `render` sux, `widget()` rules.

Comment: OK, but c'mon: 4 days? ;) I'm going to update my private demo app this evening, so I guess I'll would have noticed it later this day. Thanks for the hint, I think this will save me some time.